# Bundle install not working on Windows

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, bundler, heroku-toolbelt

I am trying to deploy my Sinatra app on Heroku server and for that i need to follow few steps. One of them is "Bundle install" but I am facing below issue while executing "Bundle install" - [I am using windows machine]
I saw many posts on this site for this error but nothing worked for me. 
Please suggest.

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using addressable 2.3.8
Using daemons 1.2.2
Using data_objects 0.10.15
Using dm-core 1.2.1
Using dm-do-adapter 1.2.0
Using dm-migrations 1.2.0
Using do_postgres 0.10.15
Using dm-postgres-adapter 1.2.0
Using do_sqlite3 0.10.15
Using dm-sqlite-adapter 1.2.0

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby22/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150515-3344-1qkfmhq.rb extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lssl... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby22/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-openssl-config
        --without-openssl-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-ssl-dir
        --without-ssl-dir
        --with-ssl-include
        --without-ssl-include=${ssl-dir}/include
        --with-ssl-lib
        --without-ssl-lib=${ssl-dir}/lib
        --with-ssllib
        --without-ssllib
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generat
e an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:541:in `try_link0'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:556:in `try_link'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:735:in `try_func'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:966:in `block in have_library'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:911:in `block in checking_for'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2 levels) in postpo
ne'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in postpone'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:910:in `checking_for'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:961:in `have_library'
        from extconf.rb:5:in `block in check_libs'
        from extconf.rb:5:in `each'
        from extconf.rb:5:in `all?'
        from extconf.rb:5:in `check_libs'
        from extconf.rb:39:in `manual_ssl_config'
        from extconf.rb:64:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/eventmachi
ne-1.0.7 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.2.0/eve
ntmachine-1.0.7/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.0.7), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.7'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve this issue. 
My development tool (Devkit) version was for 32 bit windows and ruby was 64 bit. So both were not compatible with each other.
I downloaded 32 bit version of both and followed the steps given on below links -

http://rubyonwindowsguides.github.io/book/ch02-05.html
https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit